# What is unpatched server

Tags: formsauthenticationticket

I am dealing with FormsAuthenticationTicket sharing by two different applications, on stack I found it may be the issue of unpatched server

May I know what are unpatched servers

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As per my network administrator

It is the server in which the latest patch is not installed, means its OS is not updated

Please correct if wrong, more inputs are welcome